# Log custom event telemetry from build/release agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-application-insights

I have a powershell script which imports the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` binary, to log a custom telemetry event. This works fine locally.

When creating a release pipeline to log those same events, nothing reaches app insights. From the script side, it 'successfully' submits the events, but they never appear in the AI console. Running that same script locally, the events hit AI.

Thinking something to do with powershell, I created a .net core console app to do the same thing.

Again, works fine locally, but when the release agent runs the .exe, it says it succeeds but no events hit AI.

Is there something tricky you have to do to log custom events (or any, for that matter) directly from a build/release agent?

Here is the (paraphrased) powershell code:

```
$logins = <An object which has count, some timestamp info>

# Construct the custom event. Have to use IDictionary
$event = new-object Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.EventTelemetry   
$event.Timestamp = (get-date) # Failing if not present

$metrics = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.Double]"
$properties = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"

$metrics.Add('Count',$logins.value.AuthenticationCount)        
$Properties.Add('Tenant',$TenantDomain)
$Properties.Add('StartTimestamp', $logins.value.StartTimeStamp)
$Properties.Add('EndTimestamp', $logins.value.EndTimeStamp)

$client.TrackEvent("Logins", $Properties, $Metrics)    
write-verbose -verbose "[INF]: LoginCount of $($logins.value.AuthenticationCount) added"

(From here, wait about 2 mins and this event appears in AI, when running on a local computer. Same script running on a VSTS agent = nothing appears in AI)
```

I'm in the process for creating a self-hosted agent, however I don't (yet) have any queue/pool permissions from my org. to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a client.Flush() followed by sleep of few secs, after the last Track() call.

Comment: Thanks mate that worked perfectly. Wonder why this works locally fine? Also, how do I mark your comment as the answer? Thanks again.

Comment: Flush() is required if the process is exiting, as is the case with release pipeline most likely.